# jQuery Marquee plugin - setting start position

Tags: jquery, plugins, marquee

I am using this jq plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/, ([github](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee/blob/master/README.md)). The API options are pretty limited, and there is no mention of a start position. I want it to start with the first element of the marquee aligned to the left of the container, not to the right which is default.

Here's what I have put together so far, but as you can see from the fiddle it is far from perfect:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtdLqxm7/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='marquee'>
        <div class="ablock">1</div>
        <div class="ablock">2</div>
        <div class="ablock">3</div>
        <div class="ablock">4</div>
        <div class="ablock">5</div>
        <div class="ablock">6</div>
        <div class="ablock">7</div>
        <div class="ablock">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background: black;
    color: rgb(202, 255, 195);
}
.ablock {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    margin-left:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.ablock:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}

.wrapper{
    width:50%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var offset_is_set = false;

$(function () {
    $('.marquee').bind('beforeStarting', function () {
        if (!offset_is_set) {
            $('.marquee > div > .js-marquee > .ablock:first-child').css('margin-left', '-' + $('.wrapper').width() + 'px');
            offset_is_set = true;
        }
    });

      $('.marquee').marquee({
        duration: 10000,
        duplicated: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        gap: 15
    });
});
```